# how to ignore NA in lapply?

Tags: r

```
set.seed(123)
B = matrix(  c(5, 3, 3, 1, 5, 1,3,1,NA,NA),   nrow=5,  ncol=2)
m1<-matrix(nrow=5,ncol=2,data=runif(10))
m2<-matrix(nrow=5,ncol=2,data=runif(10))
m2[1,2]=NA; ml <- list(m1, m2)
ind <- sapply(unique(c(B)), function(x) which(B == x, arr.ind = TRUE))
re <- lapply(ind, function(x) lapply(ml, function(y) y[x]))
res=lapply(re, function(x) c(t(do.call(cbind, x))))
```

but I do not know which corresponds to which.For instance:`res[[1]]` represents `5, 3, or 1 in B`? is there a way to name the output colms in `t` of its correspondence class (number) from B?

Comment: Can you explain in words what you're trying to do? what would your ideal expected output based on this input look like?

Comment: My knee-jerk response would be to say use na.rm=TRUE ... but I'm not _exactly_ sure of your aim.

Comment: You can use `na.omit` in the last line of code if the aim is to remove the NA values

Comment: I meant `lapply(re, function(x) na.omit(c(t(...`

Comment: Instead of that you can use `!is.na` or `complete.cases`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `complete.cases`

```
 lapply(re, function(x) {
         v1 <- c(t(do.call(cbind, x)))
         v1[complete.cases(v1)]})
```

Comment: @bicton  If you have used `unique(c(B))
[1]  5  3  1 NA`, it usually follows in the same order as the observations are found.  So, in this case, `5` will be `res[[1]]`, `3` as `res[[2]]` and so on....

Comment: @bicton You can set then names of `res` as `res <- setNames(res, unique(c(B)))`

Comment: @bicton You can loop through the names of `res` after setting the names, i.e. `lapply(names(res), function(nm) write.table(res[[nm]], paste0('myfile', nm, '.txt')))`  (sorry, didn't see the message earlier)